# find common index in two python list that exists in the third list

Tags: algorithm, search, hash, bigdata

I have three python lists: `list_a`, `list_b` and `list_c`. The lengths of `list_a` and `list_b` are both about 10000. The elements in the two lists are String. The length of `list_c` are about 1000. And all the elements of `list_c` exist in `list_a`. I want to find all the same indices `i` that `list_a[i] in list_c` and `list_b[i] in list_c`.

```py
list_a = create_list_a()
list_b = create_list_b()
length = len(list_a)
result = []

for j in range(1000000):
    list_c = get_list_c(some_arguments)
    tmp = [i for i in range(length) if list_a[i] in list_c and list_b[i] in list_c]
    result.append(tmp)
```

The piece of code runs slowly. Is there any method to improve the speed of this code. BTW, can bloom filter fit for this question?

Comment: what's the `j in range(1000000)` doing there?

Comment: for each j, list_c is generated by some condition

Answer (score 1):

Making `list_c` a set:

```
set_c = set(list_c)
result = [i for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(list_a, list_b)) if a in set_c and b in set_c]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two big lists that don't get updated much, so you can build a dictionary for them to avoid having to search them naively. Instead, you can iterate through `list_c` which is smaller and query them using the dictionaries. For each iteration that `list_c` is created you find the set of indices in `list_a` and `list_b` and compute their intersection in `tmp`, and append it to the result. I tried this approach and the code runs relatively much faster. I've added some indicator to see how fast the code is running.

```
dict_a = dict()
for i,l in enumerate(list_a):
    if l not in dict_a.keys():
        dict_a[l] = []
    dict_a[l].append(i)
dict_b = dict()
for i,l in enumerate(list_b):
    if l not in dict_b.keys():
        dict_b[l] = []
    dict_b[l].append(i)

for j in range(1000000):
    if (j % 10000)==0:
        print('progress = ', int(100*j/1e6), '%')
    list_c = get_list_c(some_arguments)
    indices1 = []
    indices2 = []
    for l in list_c:
        if l not in dict_a.keys():
            s1 = []
        else:
            s1 = dict_a[l]
        if l not in dict_b.keys():
            s2 = []
        else:
            s2 = dict_b[l]
        indices1.extend(s1)
        indices2.extend(s2)
    indices1 = set(indices1)
    indices2 = set(indices2)
    tmp = list(indices1.intersection(indices2))
    result.append(tmp)
```